# Target an html element inside a list with Selenium

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-ide

I'm working with  selenium, I need to target store first and second text from a list of elements.

for instance "Title 1" and "Title 2"..

```
<div class="this-list">
   <div class="item">
       <div class="title">Title 1</title>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
       <div class="title">Title 2</title>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
       <div class="title">Title 3</title>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="not-this-list">
   <div class="item">
       <div class="title">Wrong Title 1</title>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
       <div class="title">Wrong Title 2</title>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
       <div class="title">Wrong Title 3</title>
   </div>
</div>
```

What is the xPath for the texts "Title 1" and "Title 2"

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

```
//div[@class='this-list']/div[@class='item']/div[@class='title' and normalize-space(text()='Title 1')]
```

Option 2:

```
//div[@class='title'][text()[normalize-space() = 'Title 1']]
```

Answer (score 1):

using `position()` index

```
(//div[@class='this-list']//div[@class='title'])[position()=1 or position()=2]
```

**Demo:**

```js
var xpath = "(//div[@class='this-list']//div[@class='title'])[position()=1 or position()=2]";
var xpathRes = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
var matched = xpathRes.iterateNext();
while (matched) {
  console.log(matched.textContent)
  matched= xpathRes.iterateNext();
}
```

```html
<div class="this-list">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">Title 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">Title 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">Title 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="not-this-list">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">Wrong Title 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">Wrong Title 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">Wrong Title 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```